# bookshelf.js equivalent of Rails default scope (in node.js)

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Is there a bookshelf.js (http://bookshelfjs.org/) equivalent to the 'default scope' in Rails?

For example, lets say I have the model "User":

```
User = Knex.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users'
});
```

Let's also say that the user's table has a boolean field called "verified". What I want to know is if there is a way to have a default scope such that when I query the users table,

```
collection.fetch().then(function(collection) {
  // the collection contains only users with the verified = true attribute
})
```

the collection returned contains only users with the verified = true attribute

Comment: Could you elborate what you mean? Bookshelf is a ORM, there is one with Rails as well, you get it by inheriting from ActiveRecords.

Comment: I just created a npm package that does this. Just search npm install bookshelf-scopes and add it as a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookshelf [model](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-extend) (or any backbone model) allow extending both instance properties and `classProperties`.

`classProperties` attaches directly to the constructor function which is similar to `ActiveRecord`'s scope methods.

You can add `verified` method to User model's class properties like this.

```
User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
}, {

    verified:  function (options) {
        options = options || {};
        return Db.Collection.forge([], {model: this}).query(function (qb) {
            qb.where('verified', true);
        }).fetch(options);
    }

});
```

And use it like this.

```
User.verified().then(function(collection) {
  // the collection contains only users with the verified = true attribute
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution, as it allows for dynamic scopes at runtime. I'll be using this method.

Answer (score 2):

I just build an NPM package that does this using a bookshelf plugin called bookshelf-scopes.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: { filename: "./mytestdb" }
});

var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin(require('bookshelf-scopes'));
```

Now in your model you can add scopes.

```
var TestModel1 = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'testmodel',
  scopes: {
    active: function(qb) {
      qb.where({status: 'Active'});
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something on the roadmap, for now you can do something like:

```
collection.query('where', 'verified', '=', true).fetch().then(function(collection) {
  // the collection contains only users with the verified = true attribute
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also simply cache the partial query like

`var default_query = collection.query('where', 'verified', '=', true);`

and then always use that, I guess?